# checking rows and cols in a 9x9 grid

Tags: java, sudoku

I have an assignment in which I have to create the following classes:

```
public class Square3x3 {
    private int[][] mat = new int [3][3];

    public boolean allThere(){
        int[] options = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_ROWS; i++){
            for(int j =0 ; j < NUM_OF_COLS; j++){
                for (int k = 0; k < options.length; k++){
                    if(mat[i][j] == options[k]) {
                         options[k] = -1;
                         break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int num : options) {
        if(num != -1) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

a class that represents a 3x3 2d array, and a sudoku class that is constructed by a 3x3 2d array of Square3x3 objects:

```
public class Sudoku {
     private Square3x3[][] grid9x9 = new Square3x3[3][3];
}
```

I need to check if the 9x9 grid is valid, I have a method to check if a single 3x3 object is valid, but I also need to check if the entire row/col of the 9x9 grid is valid (has all the numbers from 1-9)

Comment: Can't you just iterate over a single row/column and check for the values?

Comment: but how can I iterate the entire 9 cels at one go? one row consists of three 3x3 squares

Comment: The 3x3 square is a bi dimensional array too, you can iterate one row at a time. e.g. to iterate in the first row, you can use: for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) and mat[0][i]

Comment: Your assignment data definitions make the task of checking the 9 x 9 difficult.  It would be a lot easier to create one 9 x 9 int array and pass a 3 x 3 int sub-array to the `Square3x3` class.  You'd do this by passing the row and column of the upper left of the 3 x 3 inside of the 9 x 9.  As one example, the middle 3 x 3 int array is located starting at row 3, column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to improve your data definitions using the same two classes.  Define one 9 x 9 int array, and pass a sub-array to your `allThere` method by using the row and column indexes.

```
public class Sudoku {
     private int[][] grid9x9 = new int[9][9];
}

public class Square3x3 {

    public boolean allThere(int[][] grid, int row, int column) {
        int[] options = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        for (int i = row; i < row + 3; i++) {
            for (int j = column; j < column + 3; j++) {
                options = testOptions(options, grid[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for (int num : options) {
            if (num != -1)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private int[] testOptions(int[] options, int gridValue) {
        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if (gridValue == options[i]) {
                options[i] = -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return options;
    }
    
}
```

I cleaned up your `allThere` code to document that the `break` statement only breaks out of the options loop.

Comment: thank you but the sudoku board has to be a 3x3 list of 3x3 square objects